# Why can't we find the minimum value of 2a+b?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Find the minimum value of 2a+b

```
In[27]:= Clear["Global`*"]
f[x_] = Abs[Log[x]]
Minimize[{2 a + b, f[a] == f[b], a > 0, b > 0, b > a}, {a, b}]
```

No output results

```
Out[28]= Abs[Log[x]]

Out[29]= Minimize[{2 a + b, Abs[Log[a]] == Abs[Log[b]], a > 0, b > 0, 
  b > a}, {a, b}]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
conditions = Reduce[{f[a] == f[b], a > 0, b > 0, b > a}, {a, b}, Reals]
Minimize[2 a + b, conditions, {a, b}]
```

> `{2 Sqrt[2], {a -> 1/Sqrt[2], b -> Sqrt[2]}}`

Answer (score 6):

`NMinimize` together with modified constraint gives a solution:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := Abs[Log[x]]
Plot[f[x],{x,0,2}]
```

[image]

Plot show that  condition  `f[a] == f[b]` needs constraint `b > 1 > a > 0`

```
mini = NMinimize[{2 a + b, f[a] == f[b], b > 1 > a > 0}, {a, },MaxIterations -> 1000]
(*{2.82843, {a -> 0.707107, b -> 1.41421}}*)
```

Comment: It is best to be able to calculate the exact value instead of a small value

Comment: My answer gives the numerical solution which matches quite well with @cvgmt's analytic answer

Comment: `mini /. r_Real :> RootApproximant[r]` gives the same result